# mercurial diff + unxutil "patch"

Tags: mercurial, diff, patch

How do you make the mercurial "diff" command produce output that is compatible with the unix or unxutil `patch` command?

I need to create a patch file that I can send to a coworker who doesn't have Mercurial installed.

---

I've tried using `hg diff -r 3:5 > patch1.diff` and I get an error from the `patch` command when applying it. (hold on, I will post the error message as soon as I have a chance....)

---

OK, here is a test case that I've uploaded to bitbucket:

```
hg clone https://bitbucket.org/jason_s/test-patch-apply P2base
hg update -r 2 -R P2base
hg diff -r 2:4 -R P2base > p2base.patch
rm -r P2base/.hg
cd P2base
patch < ../p2base.patch
```

I get this on my Windows PC:

C:\tmp\hg\P2base>patch < ../p2base.patch

```
patching file bar.txt
Assertion failed: hunk, file ../patch-2.5.9-src/patch.c, line 354

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, this is a documented problem (with a REALLY POOR ERROR MESSAGE) that can be overcome. From http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/patch.htm :

> On MS-Windows, the patchfile must be a text file, i.e. CR-LF must be
>   used as line endings. A file with LF may give the error: "Assertion
>   failed, hunk, file patch.c, line 343," unless the option '--binary' is
>   given.

I used `--binary` and it worked fine.